# SoundPool slowing down app

Tags: android, performance, soundpool

I have a class called Sound.java that consists of 3 functions (initSound, addSound, and playSound).

```
public static void initSound(Context con) {
    mContext = con;
    soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    streamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume / audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

public static void addSound(int index, int SoundID) {
    soundPoolMap.put(index, soundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
}

public static void playSound(int index) {
    soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

I called the initSound and addSound in the MainGame.java constructor.

```
Sound.initSound(getContext());
Sound.addSound(1, R.raw.machine_gun);
```

and called playSound inside a Thread (looping) in MainGame.java. PlaySound called every second when an event is triggered (for example, when an enemy is in sight, troops (more than one) will shoot (play the sound) continuously until the enemy is dead).

```
Sound.playSound(1);
```

The problem is when the sound plays, the app is slowing down.
I'm using soundpool because as far as I know for sound effects, soundpool is better than mediaplayer. (I've tried mediaplayer and the lag is even more.)

The sound file that I use is .wav (unsigned 8bit PCM, 1 Channel, 8000hz) with size 5.44KB.

Is there a better way to play effect sounds without slowing the game performance, or is mine wrong? I really appreciate any ideas and responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SoundPool docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play%28int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float%29), it decodes to 16-bit PCM, so you could change to that and see if you get some performance out of that. Other than that, your code seems pretty similar (at least as far as I can remember) to stuff I've done before and I didn't see any significant perf problems (I believe I wasn't even using WAV, I was just using OGGs, but I don't remember for sure). Are you trying this on an actual device, or just the emulator?

Comment: I haven't tried on actual device yet, just on the emulator. Ok, I'll try decode to 16bit pcm and post the result immediately. thx

Comment: Then I could see perf problems happening especially if you have a particularly slow machine. It's just more stuff going on. Realistically though this shouldn't be a big problem. Like I said, I've used basically the same code. The only differences I see are I used priority 0 instead of 1 (which I suppose could help) and I didn't use a HashMap to store the IDs (which I suppose eats up a little CPU time, but at one lookup a second, I can't see this being a problem).

Comment: Hi, I've tried the 16bit PCM, but it still slows the perf. and I set the priority to 0, it does make the perf a slight better, but I think it wasn't enough. I cut the 16bit PCM wav sound file with neroWaveEditor(from original length 00:00:00:690 to 00:00:00:220 ) and I get better perform but still slower than without using a sound :( and about hashmap to store the id eats up the CPU time only once(when add&init) right? I guess it's like as you say that the machine is slow, I haven't try it on actual device because I have trouble with my actual device. Thx so much for your response :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I've created a new thread for the soundpool and added 20ms sleep into the while loop. The problem is gone.